# Count distinct by same column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem that my code only shows one row value, But there should by date aka monthly/yearly based

It actually has 20 different values in "pcode".

Is my COUNT(DISTINCT ar.veakood) as pcode_total written wrong?

Based on Mysql DB.

[image]

```
select 
 ap.id as id,
 o.kirjeld_osak as department,
 ap.osakond as ID,
 ap.ladu as WH,
 ar.veakood as Pcode,
 COUNT(DISTINCT ar.veakood) as pcode_total,
 v.kirjeldus as pcode_desc,
 month(ap.loomiskuupaev) as month,
 year(ap.loomiskuupaev) as year,
 concat(ap.ladu,ap.osakond, month(ap.loomiskuupaev), year(ap.loomiskuupaev)) as UniqID

from akt_pais ap,
 akt_read ar,
 kliendid_grupp kg,
 osakond o,
 veakoodid v,
 admins a
where ap.id=ar.pais_id 
 and ap.grupp=kg.id_klient 
 and ap.osakond=o.nr_osak 
 and ar.veakood=v.veakood 
 and ap.looja=a.admin_id 
 and ap.Loomiskuupaev >= '2019-01-13' and ap.Loomiskuupaev <= '2020-02-25'
```

Comment: Thanks for the down vote, but at least can anyone explain what I have done wrong or what concept I do not get.

Comment: You need a GROUP BY to get that COUNT(DISTINCT ar.veakood).

Comment: Tip of today: Use the modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: You should activate ONLY FULL GROUP BY mode, then you'll understand why you're only getting one row

Comment: @melx "What have I done wrong"?  For starter, you code won't even execute in 99% of the dbms systems.  Look up how to use `GROUP BY`.  Lastly, this is 2020.  Please learn how to use proper `JOIN`.  It's been around for over 25 years.

Comment: @melx . . . I didn't downvote, but you should learn to use modern, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I know how to use join-s, but because I have to deal with an "old school" DB admin who is my "mentor" and is stuck on the old ways he prefers that I use it like this. So to please him I do it like that.

Answer (score 0):

You must use GROUP BY clause whenever you are using other columns along with any aggregate functions. So probably you need -

```
select ap.id as id,
       o.kirjeld_osak as department,
       ap.osakond as ID,
       ap.ladu as WH,
       ar.veakood as Pcode,
       COUNT(DISTINCT ar.veakood) as pcode_total,
       v.kirjeldus as pcode_desc,
       month(ap.loomiskuupaev) as month,
       year(ap.loomiskuupaev) as year,
       concat(ap.ladu,ap.osakond, month(ap.loomiskuupaev), year(ap.loomiskuupaev)) as UniqID
from akt_pais ap
join akt_read ar on ap.id=ar.pais_id
join kliendid_grupp kg on ap.grupp=kg.id_klient
join osakond o on ap.osakond=o.nr_osak
join veakoodid v on ar.veakood=v.veakood
join admins a on ap.looja=a.admin_id
where ap.Loomiskuupaev >= '2019-01-13' and ap.Loomiskuupaev <= '2020-02-25'
group by ap.id as id,
         o.kirjeld_osak as department,
         ap.osakond as ID,
         ap.ladu as WH,
         ar.veakood as Pcode,
         v.kirjeldus as pcode_desc,
         month(ap.loomiskuupaev) as month,
         year(ap.loomiskuupaev) as year,
         concat(ap.ladu,ap.osakond, month(ap.loomiskuupaev), year(ap.loomiskuupaev));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want one row for every month/year pair you should `GROUP BY` year and month.

This can be done by adding `GROUP BY year(ap.loomiskuupaev),month(ap.loomiskuupaev)` in the end of your query.

I could not test it since you do not provide an sql fiddle but something like this should work:

```
select 
 ap.id as id,
 o.kirjeld_osak as department,
 ap.osakond as ID,
 ap.ladu as WH,
 ar.veakood as Pcode,
 COUNT(DISTINCT ar.veakood) as pcode_total,
 v.kirjeldus as pcode_desc,
 month(ap.loomiskuupaev) as month,
 year(ap.loomiskuupaev) as year,
 concat(ap.ladu,ap.osakond, month(ap.loomiskuupaev), year(ap.loomiskuupaev)) as UniqID

from akt_pais ap,
 akt_read ar,
 kliendid_grupp kg,
 osakond o,
 veakoodid v,
 admins a
where ap.id=ar.pais_id 
 and ap.grupp=kg.id_klient 
 and ap.osakond=o.nr_osak 
 and ar.veakood=v.veakood 
 and ap.looja=a.admin_id 
 and ap.Loomiskuupaev >= '2019-01-13' and ap.Loomiskuupaev <= '2020-02-25'
GROUP BY year(ap.loomiskuupaev),month(ap.loomiskuupaev)
```

Comment: How is that not useful comment?  If you want to post an answer, post a proper code.

Comment: You lack technical knowledge to answer the question, thus I commented.